# Unable to get owin context in asp.net identity

Tags: c#, .net

I am learning asp.net identity and I create 3 project, first project I store 'Identity', second project is about accountservice' and the last is web ui 'AccountManagerController'. when I call to accountservice it occur error about owin.environment  not found in the context.
Here is code about AccountManagerController:

```
IAccountService _accountService;
    Web.Service.Interfaces.ICurrentUserProvider _currentUserProvider;
    public AccountManagerController(IAccountService accountService,Web.Service.Interfaces.ICurrentUserProvider currentUserProvider)
    {
        _currentUserProvider = currentUserProvider;
        _accountService = accountService;
    }
```

CurrentUserProvider class in service project:

```
public IAuthenticationManager _authenticationManager;
    IAuthenticationContextProvider _authenticationContext;

    public CurrentUserProvider(IAuthenticationContextProvider authenticationContext)
    {
        _authenticationContext = authenticationContext;
        _authenticationManager = _authenticationContext.GetAuthenticationContext();
    }
```

This is class implement from interface:

```
public class AspnetAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationContextProvider
{
    private IAuthenticationManager _authenticationManager;
    public IAuthenticationManager GetAuthenticationContext()
    {
        if (_authenticationManager == null)
        {
            _authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
        return _authenticationManager;
    }
    public AspnetAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        _authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }

}
```

The error occur this line

```
public AspnetAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        _authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }
```

Error: "owin.environment item was found in the context"

Please hep me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are these three projects? Are all of them webapplication projects with identity framework? If you're learning Identity, shouldn't you start with the simplest scenario possible, like making only one project, and get it to work?

Comment: yes, it's a web application, I can build identity framework in one project , now i want to separate them.